# window.addEventListener('unload', function () { } not working on Mac Safari. It works fine on Chrome

Tags: html, ajax, addeventlistener

I'm trying to add bounce reporting  for my landing page and have added the following code in Javascript (prefer to use pure Javascript).

```
window.addEventListener('unload', function () { 
     this.alert("unloading page");
     reportBounce(); 
 });
```

In reportBounce() I make an AJAX call to let the server know. I don't care about the response and am not showing a popup or anything.

The reportBounce fires up when on Chrome browser on Mac, but it does not fire when on safari on Mac. I am yet to try other browsers and OS combinations.

I've seen several questions, some talk about Back/Forward cache, some about Safari on IOS and using 'pagehide' instead of 'unload' but none that actually worked for Safari on Mac.

I was hoping there be a standard function that does the check for browser 
and adds the correct event for this need.

Please advice on how to get this to work. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried onunload, probably you should try that

Comment: @DevFeranmi. Thanks, I tried and that doesn't work either.